# How to implement vertical ViewPager with this animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-viewholder

I have two fragments and they should be inside vertical ViewPager with this animation: [link](https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4#.kay3s9ofc)

How to implement vertical ViewPager with such animation?